# how to load specific attributes from two table to another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to load attributes from two tables to one table.

I have a Location table:

```
Id  City       State     Country
===============================
1   New York   New York  USA
2   Portland   Oregon    USA
3   Tokyo      Honshu    Japan
```

And a User table:

```
Id  First_Name  Last_Name  Hometown_City  Hometown_State  Hometown_Country
===========================================================================
1   Brett       Burr       New York       New York        USA
2   Bucky       Beaver     Portland       Oregon          USA
3   Ranma       Saotome    Tokyo          Honshu          Japan
```

I'm creating a new table for users, which instead of containing the separate `Hometown` fields, has a `Hometown_Id` foreign key.

Something like:

```
Id  First_Name  Last_Name  Hometown_Id
========================================
1   Brett       Burr       1
2   Bucky       Beaver     2
3   Ranma       Saotome    3
```

However, I'm having a problem with the syntax when inserting the data into the new Users table.

I can insert the non-location based fields easily with a command like:

```
INSERT INTO newusers (Id, First_Name, Last_Name) 
SELECT DISTINCT Id, First_Name, Last_Name 
FROM users
```

However, I'm not sure of the correct syntax to then add the values from the location table

Comment: You probably want to JOIN the two tables on (city, state, country).

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean? Which two tables should I join, and what would be the result of this?

Comment: I don't think you mean "attributes", I think you mean data.  An attribute of a table would be the number of columns it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the appropriate constraints, and that the `Location` table contains unique entries, the following should work:

```
INSERT INTO newusers (Id, First_Name, Last_Name, Hometown_Id)
SELECT users.Id, users.First_Name, users.Last_Name, locations.Id
FROM users
INNER JOIN locations
ON locations.City = users.Hometown_City
AND locations.State = users.Hometown_State
AND locations.Country = users.Hometown_Country
```

If you have more than one location needed (such as a 'current residence' entry), alias and join to the `locations` table (from `users`) a second time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I get an error saying that
Hometown_Id
Invalid Identifier

Comment: @ByungkuneChoi that's likely because `Hometown_Id` isn't present in one of the tables mentioned

Comment: @ByungkuneChoi - If you'll notice, I edited your question to make it more obvious what was going on (by formatting your query, and cutting down the number of columns you were listing - `hometown` and `current` were basically the same idea).  You're going to have to modify your query to fit what your actual table structure is; take heart, this is a good learning opportunity!